# RandomizedSearchCV-Appropriate hyper-parameter distribution

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

In "Hands-on Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras & TensorFlow" book I see below distributions(reciprocal and Expon) being applied for Hyperparameters C and gamma. How did Author(Aurelion) came up with these **distributions** ? I mean how to determine which distribution would be appropriate for application in **RandomizedSearchCV** ?

param_distribs = {
'kernel': ['linear', 'rbf'],
'C': **reciprocal**(20, 200000),
'gamma': **expon**(scale=1.0),
}

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory & methodology.

Comment: I found below comments in sample code on Github.                                               
 C-->The distribution we used for C looks quite different: the scale of the samples is picked from a uniform distribution within a given range, which is why the right graph, which represents the log of the samples, looks roughly constant. This distribution is useful when you don't have a clue of what the target scale is:

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got the question right.

It depends on the ML model. Randomized or Grid Search is used to the search for the best hyper-parameter that would result in the best estimator for prediction.

For example, consider the following code example. The ```rf_clf`` is the Random Forest model object. The param_distribs will contain the parameters with arbitrary choice of the values.

```
from scipy.stats import randint

param_distribs = {
        'n_estimators': randint(low=1, high=500),
        'max_depth': randint(low=1, high=10),
        'max_features':randint(low=1,high=10),
        
    }

rf_clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)
rnd_search_rf = RandomizedSearchCV(rf_clf, param_distributions=param_distribs,
                                n_iter=10, cv=5, scoring='accuracy', random_state=42)
rnd_search_rf.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

The best estimator can be accessed via

```
rnd_search_rf.best_estimator_
```

Answer (score 0):

I found below comments in sample code on Github.
C-->The distribution we used for C looks quite different: the scale of the samples is picked from a uniform distribution within a given range, which is why the right graph, which represents the log of the samples, looks roughly constant. This distribution is useful when you don't have a clue of what the target scale is Reciprocal-:The reciprocal distribution is useful when you have no idea what the scale of the hyperparameter should be (indeed, as you can see on the figure on the right, all scales are equally likely, within the given range), whereas the exponential distribution is best when you know (more or less) what the scale of the hyperparameter should be.